# Phonegap ErrorURL

Tags: android, ios, cordova

The [Phonegap documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/platforms/android/config.html) indicates that it is possible to get the app's browser wrapper to load a custom error URL instead of showing a generic message should the application encounter an error. I find myself asking two questions here:

1. From what I can tell this is an Android-only feature. So is there an equivalent method for iOS?  The [Phonegap iOS documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/platforms/android/config.html) does not say anything on the subject.
2. Secondly, can the error URL point to a separate HTML document in the project/www folder from which the application will be built or does it have to be an external URL. My thinking is that an external URL does not in fact make much sense - what if the application error happens when the user is not on a network?

I'd be most obliged to anyone who might be able to calriify these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From OP**

> From what I can tell this is an Android-only feature. So is there an equivalent method for iOS? The Phonegap iOS documentation does not say anything on the subject.

There appears to be [no equivalent for iOS](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/platforms/ios/config.html) in the documentation. You can safely assume, if it is not there, it is not available.

To be clear, the underlying iOS library has no default error method. On Android, there is a method for dealing with this.

> Secondly, can the error URL point to a separate HTML document in the project/www folder from which the application will be built or does it have to be an external URL. My thinking is that an external URL does not in fact make much sense - what if the application error happens when the user is not on a network?

Your assumption is correct. The "error.html" should be on the device and in the `www/` directory. The file should **NOT** be on the network/internet. You'd be surprised how many times I see this error.